# Install debug flash player in Chrome?

Tags: ubuntu, chrome, debugging, adobe-flash

I am trying to adapt the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804424/how-do-i-install-the-flash-debug-player-in-chrome), [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enable-flash-player-google-chrome.html#main-pars_header), and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/171929/installing-flash-debug-for-chrome-when-not-installed-in-default-location) to install the debug version of the flash player on my Ubuntu 13.04 installation such that Chrome 30.0.1599.66 can use it.

Interestingly, it appears that I already have the official Adobe flash plugin installed and useable by Chrome, so the problem changes from "installing flash" to "replacing regular flash with the debugger version".

[image]

So I need to replace `libflashplayer.so` with the one downloaded [from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html). Sounds simple.

I selected [this file](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_plugin_debug.i386.tar.gz) (Linux Flash Player 11.2 Plugin content debugger), decompressed it and installed the Flash Player Local Settings configurations files [as directed](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enable-flash-player-google-chrome.html#id_27949).

I then replaced `/usr/lib/flashplugin/installer/libflashplayer.so` with the version included in the debugger install, and restarted Chrome. To my surprise, the second Adobe Flash Player listing in `chrome://plugins` just disappeared!

[image]

It's as if Chrome doesn't like the debugger plugin for some reason. I tried various things to get the debugger plugin to appear but to no avail:

- `chmod +rx libflashplayer.so`
- `nspluginwrapper -i libflashplayer.so` (Results in error `no appropriate viewer found for libflashplayer.so`)
- `mkdir /opt/google/chrome/plugins; mv libflashplayer.so /opt/google/chrome/plugins`

How can I get Chrome to recognize the Flash debugger plugin?

Comment: 64-bit. `Linux ckleinlx 3.8.0-31-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 10 20:03:44 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out while trying to get it to work for Firefox! This is based from the direction I found [here](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-adobe-flash-plugin-in-ubuntu-12-04both-3264-bit).

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs nspluginwrapper
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/flash-plugin/
wget http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_plugin_debug.i386.tar.gz
tar xzvf flashplayer_11_plugin_debug.i386.tar.gz
sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/flash-plugin/
sudo chmod 775 /usr/lib/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so
cd /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
rm -rf npwrapper.libflashplayer.so # Not sure if this part is necessary or not
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so .
sudo chmod 777 libflashplayer.so
sudo nspluginwrapper -i /usr/lib/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so
#                       ^ Use the full path here as a relative path won't work!
```

Now restart Chrome and Firefox. Both should be using the debug version of the flash plugin!

Comment: Still testing, but I think what I needed was to install `libnss3:i386`, since ia32-libs isn't available in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I also needed to install firefox:i386. Since it looks like I'll be using 32 bit firefox for a while, I installed `p11-kit:i386` and `libpam-pkcs11:i386` to help squash some warning/errors.

Comment: Also note: the only thing in my /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/ folder is the 'npwrapper.libflashplayer.so' file that nspluginwrapper created.

Answer (score 0):

Chromium doesn't allow you since it's a 32-bits library:

```
$ file /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so.bk
/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so:    ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so.bk: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

(Obviously, the `.bk` is my backup)

I would use the 32-bit system to debug Flash.

(I don't have a 32-bit system right now, will update later)

Comment: It doesn't have to be that way, Braiam: `file /opt/google/chrome/chrome` -> `/opt/google/chrome/chrome: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object` and `.mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object`.

Comment: @goldilocks sorry, what?

Comment: You've said that the problem has something to do w/ 32 vs 64 bit binaries, and I'm just pointing out both things (chrome and flash) are available in both versions. The only clue Cory has provided is a link to the 32-bit debugger version.  You may be right, but in that case, Cory obviously does not understand the difference and *you didn't explain it*.  What? What? Who knows? Why bother?  Do you see the point I am vaguely hinting at? ;/   You've perhaps intuited the real problem! But you did not actually say what you intuited.  What is it? ;/ ;/