# Flash Debugger on Slackware 64

Tags: 64bit, slackware, adobe-flash, 32bit

Given a fresh install of Slackware64, how can I install the 32-bit [Flash Plugin content debugger](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) in Firefox and Chrome?

Reading through [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93475/install-debug-flash-player-in-chrome) question, I've got pretty close, but I'm stuck with with the error: `nspluginwrapper: no appropriate viewer found`. Unfortunately, there's no [SlackBuild](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113718/19595) for the Debug version of the flash plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option that I use is to install 32-bit Firefox along side 64-bit Firefox and drop the debug version of libflashplayer.so into /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/. Then use a 32-bit instance to do the flash debugging.